# String - Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

I have a problem with this code. I am using a gcc compiler and when i compile and execute this code i am getting a seg fault. I am just assigning two variables, name_1 as pointer and name_2 as string. When i am trying to provide string input for the two values i am getting a seg fault. This seg fault is always associated with the pointer variable that i am using.

Below i have provided the code and the screenshot of the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char *name_1 ;
char name_2[10] ;

/*      Getting 2 strings as an input from the user
        and is stored in the pointer variable name_1 and name_2*/
scanf("%s",name_1) ;
scanf("%s",name_2) ;

/*      Printing the values of the varibales 
        name_1 and name_2 in string format      */
printf("\n%s",name_1) ;
printf("\n%s",name_2) ;

printf("\n\n") ;
return 0 ;
}
```

Please help me in this code.

[image: Seg fault]

Comment: It is not a good idea to alter the question so as to make the answer already provided invalid.  It is OK to leave the original — perhaps as a comment — and show a correction; it is not OK just to correct the code and invalidate the answers you've been given.

Comment: Note that if you were using GCC and you compiled with `-Wall`, you'd have received warnings from the compiler about your mistake.  Make sure you do compile with (at least) `-Wall` if you're using GCC.  If you're using some other compiler, then find out how to turn on more warnings.

Comment: Sir,
Now i am actually having more doubts. Whenever i am declaring a variable, is it not allocating a space?

Comment: The space for `name_1` was allocated; it is a `char *`, so enough space for storing one `char` pointer was allocated.  One part of the trouble is that you never initialized the pointer to point to something.  Another part of the trouble is that `scanf()` not only assumed that the pointer was initialized, it also assumed it was initialized so that it pointed to an area of memory big enough to store the string to be read by `scanf()`, including the terminating null.  By changing the definition of `name_1` to, say, `char name_1[20]`, you ensure that there are twenty bytes of space for the string.

Comment: [...continued...]  If you change it to: `char name_0[20]; char *name_1 = name_0;` then you have allocated space for `scanf()` to store the data in, and initialized `name_1` to point to that space.  However, you can subsequently change your mind and make `name_1` point to a different area (eg `name_2`) if you want to.  Which makes most sense depends on what you're going to do with `name_1` after you've read the data.

Answer (score 3):

`char *name_1;`, is a pointer. Initially, it points to some random garbage. You then ask `scanf` to place a string at whatever random garbage address `name_1` happens to point to when your program starts; this is undefined behavior. A conformant C implementation could have this program work as expected only on Tuesdays if it wants. :)

If you're going to pass a pointer, you have to make sure it points to a valid buffer first.

Moreover, you have a level of indirection violation in your call to `scanf` -- `name_1` is already a pointer. You don't want to pass a pointer to a pointer to `scanf`; just a pointer.

Comment: So. Will this work if the name_1 pointer is initially pointed to NULL and then used in scanf?

Comment: @Rajan: No. `scanf` will never allocate the buffer for you. This is one of the reasons that `scanf` is never safe to use in production code; because allocating a buffer of the correct size is impossible.

Comment: No; it will crash if `char *name_1 = NULL;` is passed to `scanf()`.

Comment: @Jonathan: It will crash *if you are lucky* -- again, that is undefined behavior, and undefined behavior means a conformant implementation could allocate a buffer for you on Tuesdays, crash on Wednesdays, and format your hard disk on other days. (Of course in this case crash is the most likely scenario :)

Comment: You're correct; I've over-simplified the comment.  No; on most real systems these days it will crash if `char *name_1 = NULL;` is passed to `scanf()`, but the behaviour is undefined and the runtime can do anything it likes, including making it look like it more or less worked.  The latter case is scary because the code shouldn't work.  With a NULL pointer, though, you most often will get a crash.

Answer (score 2):

The original version of the question contained:

```
char *name_1;
...
scanf("%s", &name_1);
```

The question has since been revised to contain:

```
char *name_1;
...
scanf("%s", name_1);
```

You haven't allocated any space for `name_1` to point to.  You also passed a `char **` (namely `&name_1`) to `scanf()` with a `%s` format which expects to be given a `char *`.

Possible fix:

```
int main(void)
{
    char name_1[20];
    char name_2[10];

    scanf("%s", name_1);
    scanf("%s", name_2);
```

Another possible fix:

```
int main(void)
{
    char name_0[20];
    char *name_1 = name_0;
    char name_2[20];

    scanf("%s", name_1);
    scanf("%s", name_2);
```

Comment: Sir, 
What is the use of doing so? I am gonna point that to an array is a better idea. But i am wssting another 20 bytes for the array variable or maybe wasting a 8 byte for the pointer variable.

Comment: You must set `name_1` so it points somewhere valid to ensure that your program doesn't crash (or, at least, reduce its chances of crashing — you need to modify the `%s` formats to `%19s` or `%9s` to be reasonably safe). You must have space for `scanf()` to store the data it reads. If it was a megabyte of space, you'd have cause to be leery. There are few machines where 8 bytes or 20 bytes makes a difference. You're not wasting the space (though the second code fragment certainly uses more); you're using it. I'd go with the first option, but it depends on how `name_1` is used afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *name_1 ;
...
scanf("%s",&name_1) ;
```

`name_1` is a dangling pointer and you are trying to use it, which is incorrect.

Comment: Is it a dangling pointer or just an uninitialized one?  Isn't a dangling pointer one which was once valid but is no longer valid (pointing at a local variable in a function that's since exited, or pointing to dynamically allocated memory that has since been freed)?

Comment: I believe the more accurate name in this case is [wild pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers), although people do seem to use the term dangling pointer in this case even though it's not strictly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer `char *name_1` should point to something. 
As a rule follow

```
Declaring a pointer variable does not create the type of variable, 
it points at. It creates a pointer variable. So in case you are pointing 
to a string buffer you need to specify the character array and a buffer 
pointer and point to the address of the character array.
```

Recommended change :

- You can have your `char *name_1` to point to another array of characters or
- you can have it as an array..

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I am much more confused with this and i am fine now. So i can never make it like this. Only by allocating a space, i can use the code.?

Comment: By allocating space to array? I think the problem you are facing is understanding pointers. I would suggest you to read [this](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2012/readings/pointers.pdf)

Comment: Thanks sir. I am facing troubles using pointers. I am normally using arrays instead of pointers.

Comment: Read the pdf for which the link is provided.